# Why am I recieving Cannot find module 'C:\Program files\nodejs' error?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

I am facing a strange issue since past 2 days,

I am able to run npm install command successfully 
any gup command on my project directory gives this error

```sh
 internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
     throw err;
     ^
 Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
     at module.exports (G:\Work\spfx\sp-dev-fx-webparts-masteradadf\samples\react-rss-reader\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\binding.js:19:10)
     at Object.<anonymous> (G:\Work\spfx\sp-dev-fx-webparts-masteradadf\samples\react-rss-reader\node_modules\@microsoft\gulp-core-build-sass\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:14:35)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
```

I have already tried installing / uninstalling nodejs, gulp, npm almost 20 times each.

But still did not manage to resolve this error.

any help?

Comment: Yes, it seems like an issue with accessing the install directory of Node.  What is your directory structure, i.e where is the project root, and do you run gulp from that root?

Comment: Also, did anything change over the past 2 days (like to files, possibly gulp tasks or updated modules)? It may be work checking out an old commit you think works(3 days ago), and see if the issue is still there (If you use VC).

Comment: Hi @TumoMasire thanks for your reply.
My node is installed in the default location that is C:\Program Files\nodejs by using the normal wizard, using Node 8.x LTS version

The project root is somewhere in G:\spfx\projectroot\ and Yes, I am running gulp commands in the project root in the same location as npm install which runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Maybe try this: clear the npm cache - npm cache clean --force  , delete node_modules folder, run npm i to reinstall . Are you using gulp 4?

Comment: :-) done that almost 50 times since yesterday, on each version of NODE Js , I even unistalled node, tried 8,9,1,11,12,13,14 versions, hasnt helped.

Comment: I cant tell the GULP version because no gulp command runs

Comment: Gulp should be in your package.json file, as a Dependency or DevDependency section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help!

Actually nothing was wrong with GULP, it ran when , I ran the below command

```
node rebuild node-sass
```